# Python - Calling to a function within a method from another class

Tags: python, maya

I'm using Python inside of Autodesk Maya but this should apply anywhere.

I have a class called `bRigUI` and it inherits from another class called `wingUtils` inside of the file `wingUtilities.py`

I can get to the `self.gPrefix` / etc. names by using inheritance. But I don't know how to get to the functions inside of the function that's inside of the class such as `def cName(txt):`

Here is the `wingUtilities` script:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class wingUtils():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def wingUtil(self, *args):
        self.gPrefix = cmds.textField(self.prefixField, q = True, text = True)
        self.lPrefix = cmds.textField(self.leftPrefixField, q = True, text = True)
        self.rPrefix = cmds.textField(self.rightPrefixField, q = True, text = True)

        def cName(txt):
            n = self.gPrefix + (txt)
        def lName(txt):
            n = self.gPrefix + self.lPrefix + (txt)
        def rName(txt):
            n = self.gPrefix + self.rPrefix + (txt)

w = wingUtils()
```

And here is a *VERY* dumbed down UI script that is trying to call it (and is also the class with the inheritance) - this script wont work, it's just a shell to show you what I'm doing without all the clutter.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import jtWingRigAutomation.wingUtilities as wingUtilities

reload(wingUtilities)

class bRigUI(wingUtilities.wingUtils):
    def __init__(self):

        bRigUI = 'bRigUI'

        if cmds.window(bRigUI, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(bRigUI)

            bRigUI = cmds.window('bRigUI', title = 'JT Wing Rig Automation')
        form = cmds.formLayout()
        tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth = 5, innerMarginHeight = 5)
        cmds.formLayout(form, e = True, attachForm=((tabs, 'top', 0), (tabs, 'left', 0), (tabs, 'bottom', 0), (tabs, 'right', 0)))

        tab2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout('Wing Setup', parent = tabs)
        cmds.text(self.naming(), parent = tab2)

        cmds.showWindow(bRigUI)
        cmds.window(bRigUI, e = True, w = 250, h = 500)

b = bRigUI()
```

What do I enter in the UI script to call to the function `cName` within the method within the `wingUtils` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. `cName` is a local variable which only exists within the function context of `wingUtils.wingUtil`, and is only accessible via code within that function.

Comment: Which is why declaring functions inside functions is considered poor form amongst all python programmers I know. Better to declare them in the class, possibly with a preceding _ if you want to indicate they're intended for private use. eg `def _rName(self, txt):`

Comment: @chmullig unless you want to create a decorator, or otherwise return a function object. But in this case it really just looks like a indentation error.

Answer (score 3):

The only way would be to move the inner functions to the outer scope. Do you have a good reason for them to be function-internal? If so, there's no way to do what you want. Otherwise you may consider rewriting that class. Currently the three functions `cName()`, `lName()` and `rName()` do absolutely nothing, because no code can call them from outside, and they're not being called inside. In this case it's as easy as unindenting them, and adding `self`:

```
class wingUtils():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def wingUtil(self, *args):
        self.gPrefix = cmds.textField(self.prefixField, q = True, text = True)
        self.lPrefix = cmds.textField(self.leftPrefixField, q = True, text = True)
        self.rPrefix = cmds.textField(self.rightPrefixField, q = True, text = True)

    def cName(self, txt):
        n = self.gPrefix + (txt)
    def lName(self, txt):
        n = self.gPrefix + self.lPrefix + (txt)
    def rName(self, txt):
        n = self.gPrefix + self.rPrefix + (txt)
```

Comment: Not sure if I can set two answers to be correct! But you're right, as is the other guy, I should have simply just moved them outside, I thought I'd be able to get at them but now I know :)